# how to fix xcdatamodel error at linker xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data, linker-errors, xcdatamodel

I made a new xcdatamodeld with 2 entities

1. stage, this one has a relationship many to level
2. level, this one has many attributes and one relationship with stage

but when I create NSManagedObject subclass from that xcdatamodeld, and build my project.. 3  errors are shown in the log

like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Stage in Stage.o
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Level in Level.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_Stage in Stage.o
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_Level in Level.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

anyone has had this trouble too?

How can I fix this error?

I am newbie at xcode and IOS programmer, thank you in advance ^^

Comment: Have you added coredata.framework in your project ?

Comment: not yet.. am I have to add coredata.framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you haven't added `CoreData.framework` in your project. For this - 
 Select `Target` Go to **Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries** then Click on **'+'** button (At below left corner), Then select the `CoreData.framework` then click on **ADD** button.

Comment: Yes, it is work.. :D

thank you vakul saini.. you are an angel from heaven... hahahaha

Comment: Ok, fine ... But remember me when you will gain the more reputation :-) .... dont forget to upvote :-)

Comment: haha.. fine.. vakul.. now I want to use coredata, I want to insert data, read , update also delete data...

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4

but I am still confuse how I use that

do you have a simple coredata sample code?
may you help me again?

Comment: well, i'm also newB in CoreData Concept. But you can start from here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html ...AND..  http://www.raywenderlich.com/11944/core-data-tutorial-updated-for-ios-5